# Linq filtering on static list

Tags: c#, linq, static

I have a static enumerable for various reasons - i find filtering does not work on it - is this correct behavior?

```
private static IEnumerable<Perms> Perms;
private IEnumerable<Perms> GetAll()
{
     if (Perms == null || Perms.Count() == 0)
        {
            Perms = _repo.GetAllPerms();
        }
    return Perms;
}

public IEnumerable<Perms> HasAccess(IEnumerable<string> roles)
{
    var allperms = GetAll().ToList();
    return allperms.Where(p => p.RoleName == "CEO");
}
```

--This always returns the original list irrespective of the where clause

Comment: `HasAccess` doesn't return anything and you should show _some conditional code_ in `GetAll`.

Comment: Also make sure that `Perms` isn't `null`.

Comment: Show us some more code please

Comment: done - the idea is Perms is set once and then not set again - loaded from memory instead of doing a repo call each time - it isn't null - the question is why does allPerms in HasAccess always return the full list and not respect the Where clause

Comment: Can you show your code that uses 'HasAccess'?

Comment: Also, doing Count()==0 on IEnumerable<T> will give performance penalty as it will have to count through all items only to determine if there is any present. Better to use Any() which will exit as soon as it hits an item.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I needed a ToList() where I'm calling the method. Linq is delayed execution.